# unitOfWork (fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork) clear cache after commitWork()

Tags: apex, fflib

I have a business process where the Opportunity and Account insertions have to be done in different uow.commitWork() because this use case is using person accounts, and for whatever reason out of my control, the opportunity record is not linked to the account, it is still linked to the contact through the contactId field. Therefore, I need to know which contact is related to the person account to subsequently create the relationship between the two. I don't know how to do it with a single transaction:

```
fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow_step1 = Application.unitOfWork.newInstance();
fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow_step2 = Application.unitOfWork.newInstance();

Account personAccount =    new Account();
Contact personContactAccount = new Contact();
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();

personAccount.RecordTypeId            =   personAccountRecordTypeId;
personAccount.FirstName               =   'FirstName;
personAccount.LastName                =  'LastName';
personAccount.PersonEmail             =   'email@email.com';
                
uow_step1.registerNew(personAccount);
uow_step1.commitWork();
        
List<Contact> contacts = ContactsSelector.newInstance().selectByAccountId(personAccount.Id);
contactPersonAccount = contacts[0];
        
opp = createOpportunity(requestDTO);
uow_step2.registerNew(opp,Opportunity.ContactId, contactPersonAccount);
uow_step2.commitWork();
```

but maybe there is a way to simplify it with a single instance, but I don't know if there is a way to delete the content after the commit, avoiding an error in the next one, something like that:

```
fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.unitOfWork.newInstance();

Account acc = new Account();
uow.registerNew(acc);
uow.commitWork();

uow.clear();

Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
uow.registerNew(opp);
uow.commitWork();
```

At the same time, with my current workaround (uow_step1, uow_step2) I am facing some challenges on the unit testing (apexMocks) as I dont know how can I reference to the uow_step1 and uow_step2.

Thanks

Comment: the first question I would ask is why do the Opportunity and Account inserts have to be done in different `uow.commitWork()`.  The second question is why are you having issues with unit testing (is it because you are using a mocking framework like apexMocks)?

Comment: @cropredy, I have modified the post with more details to answer your question about why I have to do both inserts in different statements. And regarding the second question; Yes, I do use apexMocks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, given the example above, you will need two UnitsOfWork as you need to query for an Id of the Contact after the commit of the Account.

But, for unit testing, you should be able to do the following

```
fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
// Given mock Uow
fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork mockUow = (fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.class);

// Given mockContact (as created by inserting person Account)
Contact mockContact = new Contact(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Contact.SObjectType);

// Given mock Contacts selector
ContactsSelector mockContactsSelector = (ContactsSelector) mocks.mock(ContactsSelector.class);
mocks.startStubbing();
//  stub selectors   
mocks.when(mockContactsSelector.sObjectType())
     .thenReturn(Contact.SObjectType);
mocks.when(mockContactsSelector.selectByAccountId(fflib_Match.anyId())
     .thenReturn(new List<Contact>{mockContact});
    

// Given mocks injected
Application.Selector.setMock(mockContactsSelector);
Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(mockUow);

// when code under test executed
new MyClass().doSomething();

// then verify commitWork called twice
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockEnv.mockUow,mocks.times(2)
 .description('commitwork sb called twice')))
        .commitWork();

// then verify personAccount constructed as expected
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockEnv.mockUow,mocks.times(1)
   .description('Account sb created')))
        .registerNew(fflib_Match.sObjectWith(new Map<SObjectField,Object> {
            Account.FirstName => 'FirstName',
            ...
        }));

// then verify Opportunity constructed as expected
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork)mocks.verify(mockEnv.mockUow,mocks.times(1)
   .description('Opportunity sb created linked to Account\'s contact')))
        .registerNew(
        fflib_Match.sObjectWith(new Map<SObjectField,Object> {
            Opportunity.Name => 'xxx',
            ...
        },
        fflib_Match.eqSobjectField(Opportunity.ContactId),
        fflib_Match.fflib_Match.sObjectWith(new Map<SObjectField,Object> {
           Contact.Id => mockContact.Id
        })
);
```

*Notes*:

1. We verify commitWork is called twice using the `times(2)` method
2. We mock the ContactsSelector as we need to know a value for the implicitly created Contact upon creation of the Account. This gets used in the verify of the creation of the Opportunity
3. There might be a syntax error as I typed this in directly